# Using Symbolic Link to Point to Apache Document Root Not Work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symlink

Currently I have my project directory in /var/www/html/trial_qa

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/trial_qa
        ServerName trialqa.mysite.com
        <Directory "/var/www/html/trial_qa">
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

To ease deployment versioning, I move project directory to /var/www/html/qa/201508230800, and create symlink to the folder

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root      root          29 Aug 24 09:41 trial_qa -> /var/www/html/qa/201508230800
```

But now, all link not works with error 404 Not Found (example: trialqa.mysite.com/contactus)

Adding option Options +FollowSymLinks in apache conf and .htaccess not solve the problem.

Comment: Check /var/log/apache2/error.log and access.log

Answer (score 0):

1- Use code repository (SVN, GIT) and tagging to keep record of deployment versions. Don't use directory with date_names. That is the worst thing you can do. 
2- Learn to use scripts to compile, deploy to server and change files for different environments. ANT or Gradle. 
3- Use relative path in your code.